# scala: optimize method: string compare

Tags: scala

Here is a piece of code. My question is very simple.
Is there more sophisticated way to do this in scala?

Should return true if string different with only one character.
i.e. "cat" and "cot" should be true

```
      def Compare(s1: String, s2: String) : Boolean = {

       val sArray : scala.collection.immutable.IndexedSeq[Char] = s1.map(_.toChar)

        var matchNumber : Int = 0
        var notFound : Int = 0

        sArray.foreach( (c:Char) =>{ 
            c match {
                case x if s2.indexOf(x) >= 0 =>  matchNumber += 1
                case _ => notFound += 1
            }

        }); 

        matchNumber + notFound == s1.length && notFound > 0
    }
```

Comment: not sure I understand - should "cat" and "ca" return true or false? Should the strings be of the same length to produce "true"?

Comment: yes, should be the same length!

Comment: As written you've said "eturn true if string different with only one character.". So should it return false if the strings are the same?

Comment: Yes, it should be different with only one char and length must be the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a shorter and more idiomatic version:

```
def compare(s1: String, s2: String) : Boolean = {
   s1.length == s2.length && (s1.zip(s2).count { case (c1, c2) => c1 == c2 } >= s1.length -1)
}
```

For example:

```
println(compare("same", "same")) // true
println(compare("same", "sDme")) // true
println(compare("same", "sam"))  // false
println(compare("same", "sDDe")) // false
```

Comment: Just to give some background: the three key Scala concepts to remember here are (1) In Scala, Strings can be implicitly converted to sequences of `Char`s (which is cool); (2) Scala collections have a `zip` method to match each element to the element at the same index in another collection, and (3) always prefer an immutable implementation

Comment: Not idiomatic because you always walk the length on failure. Also, prefer `zipped`: `(s,t).zipped.forall { case (x, y) => x == y }` or `(0 until s.length) forall (i => s.charAt(i) == t.charAt(i))`.

Comment: will ask a bit stupid question. What is it "idiomatic" ?  type of algorithm?

Comment: From Wikitionary: _"Idiomatic: pertaining or conforming to the mode of expression characteristic of a language"_. In this context, _idiomatic Scala_ means code that is written in the style and form intended and promoted by Scala, which translates to proper use of concepts like immutability, pure functions, minimizing side-effects etc.